# How can I read and search from file in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, file, search, jtable

**What I want to do in this code:** When the search button is clicked it will read a `file` then match the search values with the data inside the `file` & will show the search result in the `jTable`.

**Problems I am facing:** If GPA is selected A+ then it shows A+, A- both & when I press the search button again after giving another search value, the table just adds more data in it.

**Solutions needed:** I want to just read the file and show only the results in the `jTable`, not adding the results again & again. The search button should do search in the GPA & Class columns only. & when GPA is selected "A/B/C+" or "-" the search result should give only the data containing that particular GPA.

***NOTE:*** I don't want to change the search options.

I m a total newbie in JAVA. So any kind of help would be appreciated! :)

[Screenshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WgGz.jpg)

```
private void srchBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    //file read
    String filepath = "E:\\Netbeans workspace\\modified\\Project\\Info.txt";
    File file = new File(filepath);

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

        Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++){
            String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
            model.addRow(dataRow);

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReceiverF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //search from file
    String bGroupSrch = (String) jComboBoxBGroup.getSelectedItem();
    if(positiveRBtn.isSelected())
        bGroupSrch = bGroupSrch + "+";
    else if(negativeRBtn.isSelected())
        bGroupSrch = bGroupSrch + "-";

    String areaSrch = (String)jComboBoxArea.getSelectedItem();

    if (bgGroup.getSelection() != null) {

        filter(bGroupSrch);
        filter(areaSrch);
    } else {
        SrchEMsg sem = new SrchEMsg(this);
        sem.setVisible(true);
        sem.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

//Filter Method
private void filter(String query){
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr= new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(tr);

    tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the table just adds more data in it.

When you start the search you do:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

to clear the data in the table model of the table.

Or the easier solution is to NOT reload the data all the time. Instead you just change the filter that is used by the table.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). The code there replaces the filter every time a character is typed.

Your code will change the filter when the search option is changed.

Comment: oh man thank you so much, everything is working now! thanks a lot!